# Is a tensor(multidimensional array) an effective storage type for the tree lookahead data?

Tags: c++, performance, multidimensional-array, storage, tensor

I am investigating one game algorithm and thinking how to improve it. There is a lookahead tree. This is a very common scenario, like in card or other similar games. Game strategy is implemented as a tensor(multidimensional array). The number of dimensions = lookahead depth. And each dimension size is the MAX possible number of actions available in that depthlevel of the tree. One node at the same level can have only 2 actions available and the other 10. But we need to have a dimension of size 10 if we are using the tensor. Also we need to store the other structure with actions count for all nodes. There are a lot of operations that is made with this tensor like elementwise multiplication, addittion, etc. Total size of this tensor is couple gigabytes.  Is this tensor a good idea or not in the terms of performance? Can I do better with custom structure? The app is extra performance heavy.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like memorization of game theory.

Luckily we don't have a to dimension each level from the outset using something like this:

```
class Moves {
  TheMove thisMove; // A2-A3
  std::vector<Moves> positions; // all possible counter moves
... add stuff
};
```

This will explode horribly in size as you mentioned. The advantage is that you don't need to recalculate if you have mapped the total possible amount of moves in the entire game.

If you don't map the entire game, you will have to discard (x-1)/x of the tree each move and extend the end nodes a level.